# Box like value in struct in no_std context

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I'm trying to move over the core part of a library to use `no_std`.

Essentially an important new type is this:

`struct Packets(Box<[Packet]>);`

This way it's ensured `Packets` can be stored in a way to ensures it's continuous in memory and the `impl` block of this struct provides a few important methods. Now in a `no_std` context I cannot use `Box`. Is there some struct which allows a struct to hold an owned slice of data?

Edit:

My question is NOT that I want to use box in a `no_std` context. I need a subset of the features Box provides (Namely storing an owned piece of data in a Struct, nothing else). I don't want to include allocation, because I'm not looking to allocate anything.

A bad way to achieve what I want is to store a length and a raw pointer in the struct

```
 Packets{ len: usize, ptr: *mut Packet }
```

This way I can write my `impl` block and let used choose how they want allocate. It sucks a lot though because of unsafe usage, manual memory management and in general I don't want pointers for something that, morally, should be possible with a normal language construct.

Comment: You can't have dynamically sized data on the stack in Rust, so you either need to allocate a fixed-length array on the stack, or you need to have some kind of allocator. If you have an allocator implementation for your environment, you can also use the `alloc` crate even in `no_std`.

Comment: The creation of the `Packets` struct can be done later. It doesn't have to be done in the library. I simple only want to have this struct definition + impl block. I'm not asking for using Box in this context. I'm asking for something that looks like box without any allocation. I don't want to call new or anything like that.

Comment: "I'm asking for something that looks like box without any allocation". Then _where_ should `Packet`s be stored? They must be allocated _somewhere_.

Comment: Where they are stored should up to the user of the library. The user may decide they are stored in `Vec` or in static array or whatever they want. I essentially want to wrap an arbitrary indexable owned structure

Comment: Essentially a "way" to do this is go full C. But I don't really want to do that. 

pub struct Packets{
    len: usize,
    ptr: *mut Packet
}

Comment: Using `alloc::Box` is the straightforward translation, which provides the intended feature of _"storing an owned piece of data in a Struct"_ in an environment without `std`. If the length of the data is arbitrary, you won't be able to hold it in the stack anyway (at least not without some very obscure hacks).

Comment: _"Where they are stored should up to the user of the library."_ Maybe then you are open to the possiblity of the data being _borrowed_ instead of owned? `struct Packets<'a>(&'a [Packet])` If not, you are still better off bringing `alloc` in.

Comment: `struct Packets { len: usize, ptr: *mut Packet }` is basically a borrowed slice without the borrow checking. Don't do that, use an actual slice instead, as suggested by E_net4.